# Check when virtual desktop is switched c# winform

Tags: c#

When switching between desktops the shadow of my form has seems to be left behind. Is there a way I can check for when the desktop is switched?

Comment: 'seems to be left behind' --- what does that mean, can you provide more details?

Comment: [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/733067207218692222/859817375855542282/unknown.png)

Comment: start by sharing code to help us to help you.

Comment: there is no code related to this to share

Comment: Can you try to change your form property to always on top??